# Best fit of two geojson

Tags: leaflet, gis, openstreetmap, turfjs

I have two sets of geojson data. The first is a fetch from OSM of all nodes within a box. The second is a set of points along a square.

Now i want to best fit the square onto the OSM nodes. Any idea how to do so? I am working in react (Nextjs) with javascript.

This is my fetch for OSM nodes.

```
    const axios = require("axios");
    const fs = require("fs");
    
    // Define the Overpass query to fetch fountains in Munich
    const overpassQuery = `
      [out:json];
      area["name"="München"]->.searchArea;
      node["highway"](area.searchArea);
      out body;
    `;
    
    // Define the Overpass API endpoint
    const overpassApiUrl = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter";
    
    // Function to format Overpass API response to GeoJSON
    function formatToGeoJSON(overpassResponse) {
      const geojsonFeatures = overpassResponse.elements.map((element) => ({
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [element.lon, element.lat],
        },
        properties: {
          id: element.id,
          tags: element.tags,
        },
      }));
    
      return {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: geojsonFeatures,
      };
    }
    
    // Function to fetch data from Overpass API and save as GeoJSON
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        // Make a POST request to Overpass API
        const response = await axios.post(overpassApiUrl, overpassQuery);
    
        // Format the response to GeoJSON
        const geojsonData = formatToGeoJSON(response.data);
    
        // Save the GeoJSON data to a file (you can modify the filename as needed)
        fs.writeFileSync("Nodes.json", JSON.stringify(geojsonData, null, 2));
    
        console.log(
          "Data has been successfully fetched and saved to munich_fountains.geojson"
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data from Overpass API:", error.message);
      }
    }
    
    // Call the fetchData function to initiate the data fetch
    fetchData();
```

BR K

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.